# Lightdm broke, have to manual login via bash

Tags: bash, login, suspend, lightdm

I had a problem with Lightdm, each time I put my pc to sleep and wake up, it showed up no user, but asked for password and none worked.

And I don't know if it's dumb, but I also ran `locate lightdm | xargs sudo rm -r -f` to remove all lightdm files

I uninstalled and reinstalled `lightdm` with lightdm-gtk-greeter and settings, but now when I boot up, it says just 2 things:

```
[ OK ] Started Light Display Manager.
[ OK ] Started ACPI event daemon.
       Starting ACPI event daemon...
```

and it flashes screen like 5 times and it stops. Nothing happens. I have to alt+f1 and manually login + `startx` to see anything.

How to fix this stuff?

Comment: Can you check the LightDM logs in /var/log/lightdm?

Comment: @Prolix http://pastie.org/pastes/10517893/text?key=jwjqvqx8v73uvyhmuiska

Comment: x-0-greeter.log just says: `Error writing X authority: Failed to open X authority /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority: No such file or directory`

Comment: Might it be a owner issue? Try typing `chown lightdm.lightdm /var/lib/lightdm/`

Comment: This link might help: [https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1328681#p1328681](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1328681#p1328681)

Comment: I don't know what it was, I tried reinstalling and copying from other systems and it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you uninstall with `--purge remove`? And did you check that both the lightdm user and group no longer exist before reinstalling? Because if it works with `su -u` it is very likely that it is a permission/ownership issue!

Comment: I did use `--purge remove` and I only tried logging on lightdm with `sudo su lightdm` but it didn't return anything. It worked finally after I did the `--test-mode` run with `sudo -u my_user`

Comment: Can you try the test mode again with the `--debug` option? (i.e. `sudo -u my_user lightdm --test-mode --debug`)

Comment: @Prolix http://pastie.org/pastes/10518452/text?key=j53ncyqozqviu716pnjvta - if I run it after logging in from default session it logs me out, but if I run it from alt+ctrl+f1 console it opens a `Xephyr` window with lightdm

Comment: Could you try:  `sudo mv /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority-BAK` and then restart lightdm `sudo service lightdm stop; sudo service lightdm start` ?

Comment: @VininG I also found this report that could help solve your problem: [https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=672686#12](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=672686#12)

Comment: @VininG The bug above or similar problems can be corrected without reinstalling using: `mkdir -p /var/lib/lightdm; chown -R lightdm:lightdm /var/lib/lightdm ; chmod 0750 /var/lib/lightdm` with root permission if needed.

Comment: I already solved it with the `--test-mode` and it works properly now. It fixed itself :) Thank you for support

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything, even copied the configuration from another computer.

Finally fixed it with writing this into console:

`sudo -u my_username /usr/sbin/lightdm --test-mode`

it opened the lightdm session in new window and I simply chose to reboot.